# Alternative to Anki (flashcard app)

Tags: open-source, flashcard, anki

I use Anki to write my diary.

> From Wikipedia: Anki is a free and open-source flashcard program that utilizes spaced repetition. Spaced repetition has been shown to increase rate of memorization. "Anki" (暗記) is the Japanese word for "memorization".[4] The SM2 algorithm, created for SuperMemo in the late 1980s, forms the basis of the spaced repetition methods employed in the program. .. The cards are presented using HTML and may include text, images, sounds, videos,[5] and LaTeX equations. The decks of cards, along with the user's statistics, are stored in the open SQLite format.

It works, but there are some features missing.

I am searching for an alternative.

Required features:

- open source
- self-hosting should be possible.
- Web GUI
- You should be able to tag cards
- For the questions and answers pure text is enough (for me). HTML would be nice
- app for android which can sync to a server and which works off-line, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, I'm using Quizlet, it's not absolutely free but enought to me. 
For me Anki is the best flashcard and I don't think there are any flash card like this. I love Anki.

Comment: If you love Anki, why do you use Quizlet?

Comment: Currently, I use both. Could you please to visit my site , I create and edit existing  Anki decks to help Vietnamese people to learn English. My site: https://np1990s.wordpress.com/gioi-thieu-ve-flash-card-anki/

Comment: I am not able to read vietnamese. I have a very different use case. I write my diary in anki. My questions look like this: "What was on Friday 13th Sept 2019?".